# Scrapy Cant Found the Login Form Error: raise ValueError(f"No <form> element found in {response}")

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I tried logging in using Scrapy on the website: https://starngage.com/plus/en-us/login.

But it seems that Scrapy can't find the login form, even though when I inspect the login form elements it's there

[login form in the inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ol5lO.png)

below is my code:

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.http import FormRequest

class chnlids(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "chnlids"
    page_number = 0
    
    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url='https://starngage.com/plus/en-us/login',
            callback=self.login
        )
    
    def login(self,response):
      return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata={
              'email': 'demo', 
              'password': 'demo'},
            callback=self.parse)

          
    def parse(self,response):
      i = 0
      if(self.page_number != 10):
        self.page_number += 1
        next_page = f'https://starngage.com/plus/en-us/influencer/ranking/youtube/all-countries?page={self.page_number}'
        yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse,meta={'dont_redirect': True, 'handle_httpstatus_list': [302]}) 
        for key in range(100):
          yield{
              "channel_id" : response.css("a.text-break::text")[i].get()
          }
        i += 1
```

I get this error:

```py
ValueError: No <form> element found in <200 https://starngage.com/plus/en-us/login>
```

I have tried to monitored my login process in dev tool, and this is the result playload from my manual login when I filled out the form :
[Login PlayLoad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fknt.png)
[Login Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSMGc.png)

can someone help me?, i really appreciate and respect whatever the answer is

Comment: The `form` element along with the rest of the contents of the page are rendered with javascript, you will not be able to parse them with scrapy alone.

Comment: @Alexander Should i use another liblary like selenium ?. its is possible to do it ?

Comment: Yes.  Selenium would work.